# Cannot read JSON file - FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, filenotfoundexception

I was following tutorial on this page http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-22-Storing-and-Retrieving-Serialized-Data because I want my app to store data in JSON file and then read it back. 2 things about the tutorial:

I press write button - works fine, then press read button and it also works, however, I close down win phone 8.1 emulator, open it again, press read button and I got the `An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'exception!` Why is that, I should have the file already on disk from previously running the app ? Or is does it get erased when I close down emulator ? Also I looked for the specified file on disk and cannot find it ! Any help ?

```C#
private const string JSONFILENAME = "data.json";

private async Task readJsonAsync()
{

    string content = String.Empty;

    var myStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(JSONFILENAME);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myStream))
    {
        content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    resultTextBlock.Text = content;
}


private async Task writeJsonAsync()
{   // Notice that the write is ALMOST identical ... except for the serializer.

    var myCars = buildObjectGraph();

    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Car>));
    using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(
                  JSONFILENAME,
                  CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, myCars);
    }

    resultTextBlock.Text = "Write succeeded";
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close the Emulator its state is is not preserved, meaning that the apps that you tested are not there when you restart the emulator. Therefore, VS will make a new install when you open up the emulator again.

The same happens when you do a rebuild of your project. Then, VS will remove the app from the emulator and reinstall it from scratch. This in turn will also result in loosing your JSON file.

When you want to make sure that your data is preserved then don't close the emulator and just use Build from within VS (VS decides from time to time to rebuild your app though).

On order to test your app more properly I suggest you have a look at the Windows Phone Power Tools (http://wptools.codeplex.com/). There you can explicitly choose to install or update a given XAP package.